# Facebook page id assignment

Tags: facebook-page

How is the page id of a facebook page assigned? Will it be different across different apps?
We are trying to build an app which requires all the pages liked by a user.
For this purpose , page ids are stored in a database.We do not want same page to be in the database twice

Comment: What have you already tried, researched, not found, etc.?

Comment: I did lot of google search but was not able to find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only User IDs are App Scoped, Page IDs are always the same. At least at the moment, of course it´s possible that Facebook changes it in the future.